# Response Content Types

Tags: mime, mime-types

What are the response content types for `.docx, .xlsx, .pptx, .zip` etc. ? Can you give me a list of all content types ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're all here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any definititve list in existance, nor is there likely to ever be, of all content types because as soon as someone creates a new file format there's theoretically a new content type. Rightly, or wrongly, I've seen the following document types associated with .docx:

- application/docx
- application/msword
- application/vnd.ms-word.document

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find some: [Internet media types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type)